# How can I access CKEditor instance in parent window from iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor instance on a parent template and I'd like to insert data into its text area from the iframe after an onclick. How would I go about doing it? This is my code so far, what am I doing wrong?

```
<br><input type="button" id="change_text" value="Change Text"` onclick="myFunction()">

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
        parent.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";  //This line works, setting parent page background to red
        parent.document.CKEDITOR.instances['id_body'].setData($('input:radio[name=temp_name]:checked').val());   //Radio button value from iframe page. This line does not work
    }   

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Just had to use
`parent.CKEDITOR.instances`
instead of `parent.document.CKEDITOR.instances`